# Program piped to itself makes quadruplicate output after Ctrl-D (EOT) pressed

Tags: shell, unix, pipe

I understand that its possible to send the output of one program to the input of another program by  using the pipeline operator `|` . I used `|` operator and concatenate  *passwd.copy* to *./foo*. So the output was duplicated whatever is read from *passwd.copy* as I expected.(Assume that *C* program is written to duplicate every string that is typed) Here is my Code:
/* Saved as e52.c */

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
  int main() {      
        char ch;      
        while ((ch = getchar()) > 0) {         
             putchar(ch);          
             if (ch != '\n') 
                putchar(ch);     
        }      return 0; 
  }
```

Command : `cat passwd.copy | ./e52`

Output: `eekkzz`

However I used `|` operator as `./e52 | ./e52` but program just takes input until I use *ctrl+d* then gives me duplicated output, but twice (i.e 1 -> 1111).
I did not understand why program waits and duplicating twice?

Comment: Please add the exact code snippets and current and actual response that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

If your program `e52` reads from standard input (and duplicates it, apparently), then running just

```
./e52 | ./e52
```

will wait for input from the keyboard.  The *second* `e52` is waiting on the first, but the first one has the default standard input which is the terminal.